# Remove columns from table in liquid (Shopify Store)

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm actually not sure what is the best way to achieve this. But I need to remove the column "GroupName" and everything under it from this table.

It is pulled from a Datafeed and how it is set up, there is no easy way to strip it using regex.

Is there a code snippet I can use to remove this?

[here is an image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdV1r.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jasie I can't provide a code as I have tried using Regex. It's impossible to use that method as stated in my op. 

How can I be expected to provide an example when I don't even know the best way to do this to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS code it will hide your first th and first td

```
<style>
table tr td:first-child {
  display:none;
}

table tr th:first-child {
  display:none;
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th >Group Name</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Specification</td>
    <td>Cache</td>
    <td>Total L2 cache 4MB; Total L3 Cache 32Mb </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```